# Design Patterns to switch between databases with minimal code change

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-batch

We are developing an application using Java and Spring Batch which currently using MySQL database . But soon we will be using Oracle and Mongo DB. Which is the design pattern or best approach  i can use in case i need to switch between different databases without doing too much code change.

Comment: Generally, you would develop an interface that does all of your CRUD operations, and then write a concrete class for each database you support.  If the database is a user option, one factory method that sets an instance of the interface to a concrete class should be the only change needed.  You will have to stick to basic SQL and avoid database-specific functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say whatever design pattern you use, The DAO layer should be always independent and it should not depend on any of the data-base type.

For example: If someone changes the DB connection string from Mysql to Oracle than it should not affect the service and controller layer.

Comment: Is there ant design pattern you can name for such implementations

Comment: Yes, please go through this link: https://www.journaldev.com/16813/dao-design-pattern
A good thought for you DAO design.